# How to read avro file using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-avro

I am trying to read avro file in jupyter notebook but facing this issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.DefaultSource
```

and I can't seem to figure out where how to get this dependency from.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("readavro").master("local").getOrCreate()

result = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.avro').load("file:///C:/Downloads/part-r-00000.avro")
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add `org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5` jar to your classpath.
Since spark-avro module is external, there is no .avro API in DataFrameReader or DataFrameWriter. So try

```
result = spark.read.format('avro').load("file:///C:/Downloads/part-r-00000.avro")
```

include the avro dependency

```
$ bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5
```

Comment: It is giving me exception Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat;)V

Comment: @user1298426 updated ans to include avro dependency

Comment: I have added spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5 in my $SPARK_HOME/jars. Should it work? because getting the same exception.

Comment: Please check the compatibility of your avro, Spark and scala version it should be same. Also check the scala version of Avro and Spark jars.

Comment: this was indeed a versioning issue.